# Getting error in this code named UnboundLocalError: on line if Levelup == 81: saying local var user referenced before

Tags: python, discord.py

Start is from like:

```
  with open('data/level','r') as file:
    to_level = file.readline()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
```

then that's the code which is giving error to me (line 44 is `if levelup == 81:`):

```
 @client.event
async def on_message(message):
 channel = client.get_channel(int(spam_id))
 if message.channel.id == int(spam_id):
   if message.author.id == poketwo:
     if message.embeds:
       embed_content = message.embeds[0].description
       if 'now level' in embed_content:
                    split = embed_content.split(' ')
                    a = embed_content.count(' ')
                    levelup = int(split[a].replace('!', ''))
 if levelup == 81:
   spam.cancel()
   await channel.send(f".s {to_level}")
   spam.start()
   with open('data/level', 'r') as fi:
                            
data = fi.read().splitlines(True)
   with open('data/level', 'w') as fo: 
     fo.writelines(data[1:])
 await client.process_commands(message)
```

but it gave me error given following:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message 
Traceback (most recent call last): 

File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 301, in _run_event 
await coro(*args, **kwargs) 
File "main.py", line 44, in on_message

if levelup == 81: 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'levelup' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Note that _research_ is required - there are lots of posts about this error already.

Comment: thank you for editing the code and teaching me how it can be asked a way more better. But I can't get any solution for it and on mobile, finding is becoming real mess . Also i am not strong enough in this stuff. Hope you Understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply declare the variable in the beginning of your function. Just set it to a temporary, or default, value.
For example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    levelup = 0
    channel = client.get_channel(int(spam_id))
    # the rest of your code
```

Comment: `@Jordan` now a new error coming stated that in line 41, `if 'now level' in embed_content:`           `TypeError: argument of Type '_EmptyEmbed` is not iterable`

Comment: I’m not all that familiar with discord.py but maybe you are trying to iterate through a function? if not, why don’t you just add an `if` statment to make sure it’s not empty, before line 41.